# instance name is declared on an object Flash AS3 what does it mean?

Tags: actionscript-3, object, flash-cs5

Scene 1, Layer 'auto button', Frame 1   Warning: The instance name 'semisideview' is declared on an object of type flash.display.SimpleButton but there is a conflicting use of the instance name 'semisideview' on an object of type flash.display.MovieClip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used same instance name 'semisideview' to SimpleButton object and MovieClip object.

So try to change an instance name.